How can I clip a line to a rectangle?
I'm trying to draw lines obtained from a Hough transform. The lines from the Hough transform have no length or end points; they are infinite.
To draw the lines, I need the end points. I can't find a good way to determine the length of the line so I multiply by 1000. I tried to come up with something better, but ChatGPT can't help me.
Do you know a better way?
def hough_lines(edges: np.ndarray, threshold: float, min_line_length: float = 50, rho: float = 1, theta: float = np.pi/180) -> np.ndarray:
    height, width = edges.shape
    diagonal = np.sqrt(height ** 2 + width ** 2)
    rho_values = np.arange(-diagonal, diagonal, rho)
    theta_values = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, int(np.pi / theta))

    cos_theta = np.cos(theta_values)
    sin_theta = np.sin(theta_values)

    accumulator = np.zeros((len(rho_values), len(theta_values)), dtype=int)

    ys, xs = np.nonzero(edges)

    for y, x in zip(ys, xs):
        rho_vals = x * cos_theta + y * sin_theta
        rho_indices = ((rho_vals + diagonal) / rho).astype(int)
        accumulator[rho_indices, np.arange(len(theta_values))] += 1

    line_indices, theta_indices = np.where(accumulator >= threshold)
    lines = []

    for rho_idx, theta_idx in zip(line_indices, theta_indices):
        rho_val = rho_values[rho_idx]
        theta_val = theta_values[theta_idx]
        a = np.cos(theta_val)
        b = np.sin(theta_val)

        x0 = a * rho_val
        y0 = b * rho_val

        x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

        lines.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])

    return np.array(lines)


in other words, you have a line (an infinite thing), and you want to clip it against the image bounds, to obtain the line segment (a finite thing)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Google line clipping provides reliable results

Please provide further details, add an image to help us understand your problem.
